# Почему пользовательское метаполе "Быстрая доставка" не учитывается при фильтрации в WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

При использовании фильтрации в WooCommerce, почему значение пользовательского метаполя "_quick_delivery" не учитывается, в то время как другие параметры, например, "min_price", работают нормально?

```
function add_quick_delivery_meta_field()
{
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
    array(
        'id'          => '_quick_delivery',
        'label'       => ' Sofort lieferbar ',
        'description' => 'Prüfen Sie, ob der Artikel für eine sofortige Lieferung geeignet ist',
    )
);
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_quick_delivery_meta_field');

// Сохранение значения пользовательского метаполя "Быстрая доставка" для товаров
function save_quick_delivery_meta_field($post_id)
{
   $quick_delivery = isset($_POST['_quick_delivery']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
   update_post_meta($post_id, '_quick_delivery', $quick_delivery);
 }
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_quick_delivery_meta_field');
```

example.com/?min_price=10 нормально работает а example.com/?_quick_delivery=1 нет

Comment: `почему значение пользовательского метаполя "_quick_delivery" не учитывается` -- именно потому что это пользовательское мета поле. [Filter products based on a custom field in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462372/filter-products-based-on-a-custom-field-in-woocommerce#answers-header)